# java multiline button - disable color-issue

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

i have the following problem:
i want a JButton with a line break. i am using the html method to get it done.

`<hmlt>Bla<br>Bla</html>`

the problem appears if i disable the button. it works fine except on the "html-styled" button. the color from the button stays the same.
on an other button i am just using `&#8592+;`(without the "+") and it works fine, the arrow gets grayed out if i disable him. 
so i searched some time for the unicode or html number for the line break, but it didn´t work(for example `&#10+;`)
so can anybody give me an advice? i know it could be done in java, but i prefer the html way, cause it is faster to implement :)

Comment: [For better help sooner, include an SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to Use HTML in Swing Components: ButtonHtmlDemo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html):

> ..Note also that when a button is disabled, its HTML text unfortunately remains black, instead of becoming gray. (Refer to [bug #4783068](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4783068) to see if this situation changes.)

Comment: thanks. i do not understand why java is so popular, i only have problems. whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think components with HTML text will be affected by the modified text style that disabling them usually causes.

You could override the button's `getText()` method to return a different HTML including styling for the text depending on whether the button is disabled or not, but if you want to get it just right it would probably be easier to extend the UI to allow multiple lines without relying on HTML.